Is converting values from reduced units to physical units a good idea?
I have written a program for MC simulation or LJ particles in NVT.
I have used reduced units to run simulations.
My professor wants me to show him data and plot it in physical units.
Is converting values from reduced units to physical units enough, or do I need to rewrite my program and run all the simulations again?
Note: I asked the same question in Physics.SE. I thought they would be faster to respond. However, I haven't received any response yet.

Converting should be fine. Note that due to the finite precision of the floating point data types (that the OP presumably used), it is possible to obtain slightly different results. It can be useful to implement the conversion in the code (after the simulation has run) to display both sets of numbers.

Alas, Physics SE is a sad, unwelcoming site.


"My professor wants me to show him data and plot it in physical units."

Your professor and I think alike: when data is being communicated, it is helpful for it to be communicated in the way that is most familiar to the audience. In very many cases, people (regardless of how much experience they have with reduced units) are much more familiar and comfortable with physical units such as "meters per second", than the extremely obscure units that you would get if you were to present the data using the information provided in the right-most column of the "reduced units" table provided here.

"Is converting values from reduced units to physical units enough, or do I need to rewrite my program and run all the simulations again?"

You do not need to rewire the entire program, since you can do the unit conversion after the calculation is done and before the results are communicated. However, if your program can do the unit conversions when the user desires, it will most likely be a more convenient program for you (and others, if you plan on the program being useful to more people) to use in the future.

When comparing a molecular simulation to one type of physical material, it does not matter whether the computer program has used "reduced units" or "real units".
The computer simply shuffles numbers. Its internal representation does not "know" whether "a distance of 3" is 3 reduced units, 3 angstroms, or 3 inches or 3 cm. Thus, as long as you are converting correctly between reduced units and "real units", for example, when specifying constant or when drawing a graph of your results, the computer program itself is fine.
Now it turns out that we use the LJ potential because it is really quite a good representation for interatomic interactions (relative to how simple it is), and sometimes the only practical way to show this relationship is by working almost entirely in reduced units. Here is a celebrated diagram from 2008 showing how the liquid-gas coexistence lines for several different noble gases falls very close to the line simulated with the LJ potential:

(Image from the paper "100 Years Of The Lennard-Jones Potential": https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.jctc.4c00135 )
This graph would be much harder to draw in "real units", with four different noble gases having different $\sigma_{\mathrm{gas}}$ and $\epsilon_{\mathrm{gas}}$, and also different experimental critical densities and temperatures.
